# How to trigger again HttpGet request in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6, combinelatest

I'm using `combineLatest` to merge data from `websocket` and `database` into one object. Each time the `websocket` sends data my data are refreshing. Although I'd like to refresh data at page manually also by pressing the button. Unfortunately `combineLatest` isn't detect that I made `HttpGet` request to get newest data.

```
export class ShowTestDataComponent implements OnInit {
  stockData: RootObject;

  private stocksData$: WebSocketSubject<MessageEvent>;
  private stocksResources$: Observable<DbObject[]>;

  constructor(private stockService: StockService, private webSocketService: WebSocketServiceService) {
    this.stocksData$ = this.webSocketService.connect();
    this.stocksResources$ = this.stockService.getStocksResources();
  }

  buyStock(code, quantityToBuy): void {
    const dto: DbObject = {
      code: code,
      quantity: quantityToBuy
    };

    this.stockService.buyStock(dto).pipe(
      mergeMap(() => this.stockService.getStocksResources())
    ).subscribe((res) => this.stocksResources$ = of(res));    
  }

  prepareStockData(): void {
    combineLatest(
      this.stocksData$,
      this.stocksResources$,
      (stockData: RootObject, stockResources: DbObject[]) => ({
        stockData,
        stockResources
      })
    ).subscribe((pair) => {
      this.stockData = JSON.parse(pair.stockData.data);

      this.stockData.Items.forEach(item => {
        item.Quantity = pair.stockResources.find(d => d.code === item.Code).quantity;
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.prepareStockData();
  }
}
```

So as you can see If I'll press `BUY` on UI then method `buyStock` will be executed and there are executing `this.stockService.buyStock(dto)` to change data in DB, and then `this.stockService.getStocksResources()` to refresh data from DB. Everything works, data are changed but data isn't refreshing (comibneLatest isn't detect any message from `stocksResources$`

Here is my service, I think that problem is in componenet though.

```
export class StockService {
  apiUrl = "http://localhost:5001/api/values";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getStocksResources(): Observable<DbObject[]> {
    return this.http.get<DbObject[]>(this.apiUrl + "/stocks");
  }

  buyStock(data: DbObject){
    return this.http.post<DbObject>(this.apiUrl + "/quantity", data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, are you sure that `this.stockRessources$' produce a new value? and what about : 

   `this.stocksResources$ = this.stockService.buyStock(dto).pipe(mergeMap(() => this.stockService.getStocksResources()));`

Comment: @GeoAstronaute With my code it hit breakpoint (`Post` to change data, and `Get` to get new data) in backend. With your code is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create new Subject.
So declare:

`private stocksResources$: Subject<DbObject[]> = new Subject();`

In Constructor you have to emit your received `stockResources` data using your `Subject`:

```
constructor(private stockService: StockService) {
  this.stockService.getStocksResources().subscribe(res => {
    this.stocksResources$.next(res);
  });
}
```

And each time you buy new stock - you have to emit your data again.

```
this.stockService.buyStock(dto).pipe(
  mergeMap(() => this.stockService.getStocksResources())
).subscribe((res) => {
  this.stocksResources$.next(res);
});
```

And that's it :)

Whole code:

```
export class ShowTestDataComponent implements OnInit {
  stockData: RootObject;

  private stocksData$: WebSocketSubject<MessageEvent>;
  private stocksResources$: Subject<DbObject[]> = new Subject();

  constructor(private stockService: StockService, private webSocketService: WebSocketServiceService) {
    this.stocksData$ = this.webSocketService.connect();
    this.stockService.getStocksResources().subscribe(res => {
      this.stocksResources$.next(res);
    });
  }

  buyStock(code, quantityToBuy): void {
    const dto: DbObject = {
      code: code,
      quantity: quantityToBuy
    };

    this.stockService.buyStock(dto).pipe(
      mergeMap(() => this.stockService.getStocksResources())
    ).subscribe((res) => {
      this.stocksResources$.next(res);
    });
  }

  prepareStockData(): void {
    combineLatest(
      this.stocksData$,
      this.stocksResources$,
      (stockData: RootObject, stockResources: DbObject[]) => ({
        stockData,
        stockResources
      })
    ).subscribe((pair) => {
      this.stockData = JSON.parse(pair.stockData.data);

      this.stockData.Items.forEach(item => {
        item.Quantity = pair.stockResources.find(d => d.code === item.Code).quantity;
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.prepareStockData();
  }
}
```